# Knaster property and being $\sigma$-centered?

Tags: set-theory

I know that both being Knaster and being $\sigma$-centered imply ccc, but how are the two related if at all? I.e. does one imply the other or are there counterexamples to both implications?

Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Centeredness implies Knasterness: Write $P=\bigcup_{i\in\omega}P_i$, where each $P_i$ is centered. Given any set $\{p_j\;|\;j<\omega_1\}$, let $F(j)$ be some $i$ such that $p_j\in P_i$. Then there is an uncountable subset $A$ of $\omega_1$ on which $F$ is constant (say with value $i$). Thus $\{p_j\;|\;j\in A\}\subseteq P_i$ is centered.

On the other hand, Knasterness does not imply centeredness: No $\sigma$-centered forcing can enlarge the continuum, so $\text{Add}(\omega,(2^{\omega})^+)$ is never $\sigma$-centered. However, it is always Knaster by the $\Delta$-System-Lemma.

Comment: Very clear! Thank you very much for this!